# MySQL - How to query across multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in my database, 'users', 'views', and 'products'.

Each user has an id and a firm_id.
Each view has a user_id and a product_id.
Each product has an id.

Given a firm_id, I would like to find a list of products that people from that firm have viewed, in order to display this data in my application.

I tried

```
SELECT p.info
FROM products p INNER JOIN
     views v
     ON v.product_id = p.id INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = v.user_id INNER JOIN
     firms f
     ON u.firm_id = f.id
WHERE f.id=$firm_id;
```

This query was accepted by MySQL but returned no results.  The problem seems pretty simple, and I'm sure people have to write queries like this frequently, but I couldn't find any similar examples online.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: As I do not know the data it might be the right answer. BTW - Is $firm_id correct

Comment: Your query looks reasonable.  Start with `select * from firms f where f.id = $firm_id` and work from there.